# Can I install IE7 and IE8 in Windows 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 and IE 11. I wanna install IE7 and IE8 to test javascript.

I followed these links to download IE7 - IE8:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-7-details.aspx
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-8-details.aspx

But, the page gave me error message:

> Internet Explorer 7(8) is not compatible with your system.
>
> You are running Windows 10 64-bit. Although Internet Explorer 7(8)
>   will not run on your system, you can download Internet Explorer 8 for
>   other operating systems.

Is there another way (or hacking) to install IE7 and IE8 in Windows 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtual machines are available for just such scenarios (testing old versions of IE). You can find them at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

EDIT
The URL for VMs in the approved answer has changed. It's now at:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Answer (score 14):

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Press F12 and select the Internet Explorer
   version to be emulated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install ie7 nor ie8 for javascript testing purpose.
Follow the 2 step instruction in the following picture (Click the link to imgur.com - not enough reputation to post images directly). Hope it help. I myself got javascript problems when accessing webs which are just compatible to IE9 and backward.

[Solution Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJEJq.jpg)

Comment: The emulation provided by IE >= 10(?) is NOT a real alternative because the emulated behaviour is NOT THE SAME as the one of the 'real' IE

Answer (score 0):

Just use BrowseEmAll and IE Collection, both allows you to run old Internet Explorer versions in newer Microsoft Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools available online where you can access all the versions of Internet Explorer. Some of them are:

- Browerling
- LambdaTest
- IE Netrender
- SmartBear
- BrowserStack