# How to configure Selenium tests to make IE8 testing possible on Windows 10

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, windows-10

I installed and successfully run IE11 tests with Selenium.
Is there any easy setup to force run IE8 for testing with Selenium?
According to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration there is nowhere mentioned how to run specific - here IE8 - version of IE and by default IE11 is run.
Should I have installed IE8 first to make those test run?

Comment: This question seems to be based on the assumption that IE8 can run on Windows 10 in the first place.

Comment: How can it run on IE8 if you don't have it on the computer? you also might have to downgrade the IE driver, I'm not sure if the latest one is compatible with this IE version.

Comment: Thanks for comments - finally I found answer on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to run IE8 on Windows10 because this is not supported configuration as @BoldClock mentioned in comment to my question.
To make this happen VirtualMachine need to be downloaded form https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ and run to make IE8 tests available.
Similar question:
[Can I install IE7 and IE8 in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046403/can-i-install-ie7-and-ie8-in-windows-10)

Comment: From your last post. I can see that you had got the answer for your question and you had posted it. I suggest you to mark it as accepted answer for this thread may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Deepak-MSFT - I need to wait one more day to do this :) since OP can accept own answer after 48h from sending question